# Preencher combo dinamicamente com MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

No meu arquivo `.cshtml`, tenho essas DIV's:

```html
<div class="grid_14">
    <select id="txtDia" name="txtDia" class="grid_2" required>
        <option>Dia</option>
    </select>
    <select id="txtMes" name="txtMes" class="grid_2" required>
        <option>Mês</option>
    </select>
    <select id="txtAno" name="txtAno" class="grid_2" required>
        <option>Ano</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Como eu faço para preencher esses caras assim:
Dia => de 1 até 31
Mes => de 1 até 12
Ano => de 1900 até Atual

Uso MVC 5, JQuery e VS 2013

Comment: Ué, perdeu a formatação. Enviei um trecho de código do meu cshtml e perdeu. Vou editar e tentar recuperar a formatação, pois é mais fácil de ler.

Answer (score 1):

Você terá algum trabalho caso queira trabalhar dessa forma, pois tem meses que tem menos de 31 dias, e anos bissextos que alteram também esses dias.

O que você pode utilizar é no seu model, no campo da data, colocar o DataAnnotation:

```cs
[DataType(DateType.Date)]
Public DateTime DataVencimento{get;set;}
```

Na View você utiliza:

```cs
<div class="form-group">                       
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataVencimento, new { @class = "col-xs-4" })
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataVencimento)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataVencimento)
        </div>
 </div>
```

Assim, vc terá toda essa parte de validação de datas prontas, usando DatePicker.
[DatePicker http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer-Blogs-Components-WeblogFiles/00-00-01-03-74-metablogapi/7737.image_5F00_477473C0.png](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer-Blogs-Components-WeblogFiles/00-00-01-03-74-metablogapi/7737.image_5F00_477473C0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi assim: Exemplo para Dia, mas vale para os demais.

```cs
<div class="grid_14">
    <select id="txtDia" name="txtDia" class="grid_2" required>
        <option>Dia</option>
            @{
                for(int i = 1; i < 32; i++)
                {
                    @:<option>@i</option>
                }
             }
    </select>
</div>
```